# seekable webm video recording duration missing

Tags: typescript, blob, mediarecorder, webm, mediastream

For making seekable webM Video (duration in video),
we are getting video in parts , i m trying to inject the duration using
TS-ebml package
Code:-

```
  const injectMetadata = (blob,durationData) => {
  console.warn("blob",blob)
  const decoder = new Decoder();
  const reader = new Reader();
  reader.logging = false;
  reader.drop_default_duration = false;

  return readAsArrayBuffer(blob).then((buffer) => {
    const elms = decoder.decode(buffer);
    elms.forEach((elm) => {
      reader.read(elm);
    });
    reader.stop();

    const refinedMetadataBuf = tools.makeMetadataSeekable(
      reader.metadatas,
      durationData * 1000,
      reader.cues
    );
    const body = buffer.slice(reader.metadataSize);
    console.log("reader.metadataSize",reader.metadataSize)
    console.warn("reader.metadatas",reader.metadatas)

    return new Blob([refinedMetadataBuf, body], { type: blob.type });
  });
};
```

after injecting duration in part 1, again replace part 1 in s3. When the video is getting completed in one go, video is playing fine with seekbar ,
But when session is closing abruptly(refresh page), we are storing part 1 in our DB separately via api by converting blob into base64, and again getting base64 to blob and replacing part 1 in s3 after injecting duration then video recorded after
refresh is not working.
For getting the exact duration of the video I am using get-blob-duration package.

webm-duration-fix package is also available  which fixes the duration in the blob but for using this we need the whole video blob at once ,in our case there is no point of time when we have all the blobs at once since we are using s3 multipart upload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get duration in reader variable.

```
const refinedMetadataBuf = tools.makeMetadataSeekable(
    reader.metadatas,
    reader.duration,
    reader.cues
);
```